# How can I select specific characters in an array without using RegEx in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am doing multiple coding challanges to join a coding bootcamp but have been stuck at the same problem for a few days now.

I have looked online, tried differen solutions, but nothing seems to pass their specific test on their console.

**Instructions**

Create a function named extractPassword which takes an array of characters (which includes some trash characters) and returns a string with only valid characters (a - z, A - Z, 0 - 9).

Here's an example:

```
extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']); // should return the string 'a1a'
extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']); // should return the string 'A7C'
```

**TRY 1:**

I first tried using a RegEx:

```
var newArray = [];

var extractPassword = function(arr){
    //in this area I display the array:
 
    console.log('arr: ' + arr);
    
    //here I transformed the array into a string with the method .join() and then looked for a match with the method .match() with the parameter of a RegExp with a g at the end so it doesn't stop after the first match:
    return arr.join('').match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/g);
};

console.log(extractPassword(['a','-','~','1','a','/']).toString().replace(/,/g, ''));
```

The end result is what I wanted: a1a

But the output on their programe gave me an error:
**>>>Code is incorrect RegExs are cool, but that is not the type of solution we are looking for.**

**TRY 2**
Then, I tried combining a function with a for loop and an if statement:

```
var newArray = [];

extractPassword(['a','-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']);

//extractPassword(['~','A','7','/','C']);

function extractPassword(arr){
    //here I console.log the array, to ensure I am passing the right value to the function:
    console.log('arr: ' + arr);
    
    //Here I atribute the array transformed into a string to the var arrayToString:
    var arrayToString = arr.join('');
    
    //Here I console.log the value of the var arrayToString to ensure I am displaying what I want: a string:
    
    console.log('arrayToString: ' + arrayToString);
    
    //Here I will use a for loop to iterate through the characters of the string, and create the var charCode, which will transform each element of the arrayToString var (i) into a Unicode value with the method charCodeAt():
    
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayToString.length; i++){
        var charCode = arrayToString.charCodeAt(i);
        //Here I console.log the different i elements of the arrayToString variable and also its charCode value:
        console.log('charCode ' + i + ':' + charCode);
        
        //Here I will insert a condition to say: 'If we have a character between a and z OR A and Z OR 0 and 9, push those characters into the newArray':
        
        if((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)){
            newArray.push(arr[i]);
            console.log('newArray: ' + newArray);
        }
        
    }

    console.log('Final string: ' + newArray.join(''));
}
```

The result that gives me here is a1a, but the console still gives me an error: >>Code is incorrect. Your function is not returning the correct value.

Does anyone have an alternative way to do what they ask for? I have tried a few other things, but I've been at this for so long, I can's get unstuck.

Comment: Your function has no `return` statement.

Comment: I don't see any issue with the 2nd approach, even I tried with the online complier... can you provide error screenshot or some thing else to understand it more

Comment: your function doesn't `return` anything, just outputs your findings to the console. Also please note that you don't have to calculate the charcode of a character to compare it, you could directly compare characters like this : `'b' > 'a' `

Comment: You probably want to use `Array.filter`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Hi @Pointy,

Thank you for the reply. I added return , and the error remains the same:

`        
        if((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || (charCode > 64 && charCode < 91) || (charCode > 96 && charCode < 123)){
            newArray.push(arr[i]);
            console.log('newArray: ' + newArray);
        }
        
    }
    
    return newArray.join('');   
}
`

Comment: @JRPCRD what value is returned from the added `return` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use the `.filter()` method to get rid of any character in the array that isn't within the ranges `0-9`, `A-Z`, and `a-z`. You can then just call `.join()` on the resulting array. Like this:

```js
const extractPassword = arr => arr.filter(ch => (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')).join('');

console.log(extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/'])); // should return the string 'a1a'
console.log(extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C'])); // should return the string 'A7C'
```

Note that you can compare the character with other characters; you don't have to call `.charCodeAt()` and then compare it with ASCII values.

Comment: You're a star! Your code worked! :D 
Thank you sooo much

Answer (score 1):

To do this without Regex, you could create an [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that leverages [String.codePointAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt), and apply that filter to your inputs, which were conveniently provided to you already in array form.

```js
const firstCodePoint = 48; // A
const lastCodePoint = 122; // 9

const isAlphaNumeric = (character) => {
  const thisCodePoint = character.codePointAt(0);
  return (thisCodePoint >= firstCodePoint) && (thisCodePoint <= lastCodePoint);
};

const extractPassword = (arr) => {
  const filteredString = arr.filter(isAlphaNumeric).join("");
  return filteredString;
};

console.log( extractPassword(['a', '-', '~', '1', 'a', '/']) ); // 'a1a'
console.log( extractPassword(['~', 'A', '7', '/', 'C']) ); // 'A7C'
```